# Convert spark scala dataset of one type to another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, scala-spark

I have a dataset with following case class type:

```
  case class AddressRawData(
                         addressId: String,
                         customerId: String,
                         address: String
                       )
```

I want to convert it to:

```
case class AddressData(
                          addressId: String,
                          customerId: String,
                          address: String,
                          number: Option[Int], //i.e. it is optional
                          road: Option[String],
                          city: Option[String],
                          country: Option[String]
                        )
```

Using a parser function:

```
  def addressParser(unparsedAddress: Seq[AddressData]): Seq[AddressData] = {
    unparsedAddress.map(address => {
      val split = address.address.split(", ")
      address.copy(
        number = Some(split(0).toInt),
        road = Some(split(1)),
        city = Some(split(2)),
        country = Some(split(3))
      )
    }
    )
  }
```

I am new to scala and spark. Could anyone please let me know how can this be done?

Comment: If your data for the dataset is attached to your case class you can use withcolumn api function to create separate columns by using split function and then cast that to new case class. That would be straight forward

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You were on the right path! There are multiple ways of doing this of course. But as you're already on the way by making some case classes, and you've started making a parsing function an elegant solution is by using the Dataset's `map` function. From the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#map%5BU%5D(func:T=%3EU)(implicitevidence$6:org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder%5BU%5D):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset%5BU%5D), this `map` function signature is the following:

```
def map[U](func: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: Encoder[U]): Dataset[U]
```

Where `T` is the starting type (`AddressRawData` in your case) and `U` is the type you want to get to (`AddressData` in your case). So the input of this `map` function is a function that transforms a `AddressRawData` to a `AddressData`. That could perfectly be the `addressParser` you've started making!

Now, your current `addressParser` has the following signature:

```
def addressParser(unparsedAddress: Seq[AddressData]): Seq[AddressData]
```

In order to be able to feed it to that `map` function, we need to make this signature:

```
def newAddressParser(unparsedAddress: AddressRawData): AddressData
```

Knowing all of this, we can work further! An example would be the following:

```
import spark.implicits._
import scala.util.Try

// Your case classes
case class AddressRawData(addressId: String, customerId: String, address: String)
case class AddressData(
  addressId: String,
  customerId: String,
  address: String,
  number: Option[Int],
  road: Option[String],
  city: Option[String],
  country: Option[String]
)

// Your addressParser function, adapted to be able to feed into the Dataset.map
// function
def addressParser(rawAddress: AddressRawData): AddressData = {
  val addressArray = rawAddress.address.split(", ")
  AddressData(
    rawAddress.addressId,
    rawAddress.customerId,
    rawAddress.address,
    Try(addressArray(0).toInt).toOption,
    Try(addressArray(1)).toOption,
    Try(addressArray(2)).toOption,
    Try(addressArray(3)).toOption
  )
}

// Creating a sample dataset
val rawDS = Seq(
  AddressRawData("1", "1", "20, my super road, beautifulCity, someCountry"),
  AddressRawData("1", "1", "badFormat, some road, cityButNoCountry")
).toDS

val parsedDS = rawDS.map(addressParser)

parsedDS.show                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
+---------+----------+--------------------+------+-------------+----------------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                   
|addressId|customerId|             address|number|         road|            city|    country|                                                                                                                                                                                   
+---------+----------+--------------------+------+-------------+----------------+-----------+                                                                                                                                                                                   
|        1|         1|20, my super road...|    20|my super road|   beautifulCity|someCountry|                                                                                                                                                                                   
|        1|         1|badFormat, some r...|  null|    some road|cityButNoCountry|       null|                                                                                                                                                                                   
+---------+----------+--------------------+------+-------------+----------------+-----------+
```

As you see, thanks to the fact that you had already foreseen that parsing can go wrong, it was easily possible to use `scala.util.Try` to try and get the pieces of that raw address and add some robustness in there (the second line contains some `null` values where it could not parse the `address` string.

Hope this helps!